# Python efficiency: importing things in things I am importing?

Tags: python, import, coding-efficiency

Let's say I am making a project, let's call it master.py as it is the master file.

```
#this is master.py
import a
import b
for i in range (whatever):
 for j in range (whatever):
  a.main(i)
  b.main(j)
```

a and b are other sub-functions which I have made, and are in other text files (for easier tweaking). Now let's say a is:

```
#this is a.py
def main(i):
 from numpy import sin
 return sin(i)
```

and b:

```
#this is b.py
def main(j):
 from random import uniform
 return uniform(0, j)
```

master.py calls functions a and b a lot of times. Each time it does, it imports sin in a, and uniform in b. This can't be efficient, but I don't know a way around it (besides putting a and b in the same text file as master.py, which I don't want to do for debugging reasons). I have tried putting the statements for importing sin and uniform in master.py instead, but then when it calls a and b, it fails because sin and uniform aren't imported. I guess it has to import them in the subroutines? Can I somehow import sin and uniform in master.py and pass them along to a and b so I don't have to import each time?

Comment: "This can't be efficient" - Do you have any evidence for that?  (i.e. that your code is running slowly as a result?)

Comment: Note that a simple solution (though I'm not claiming it actually makes a perf difference) is to simply hoist the `import`s out of the functions and up to the top level of `a.py` and `b.py`.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, it was just a remark. I assume it's not efficient to import the same thing over and over. I haven't actually built my master program yet, I'm planning out how to make it efficient before I make anything too in-depth.

Comment: While the `import` statement is executed each time the function is called, the first thing the `import` statement does is to see if the requested module has already been imported; imports are effectively memoized. That said, don't put your import statements in your function; just put them at the beginning of your module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried importing at the top of `a.py` and `b.py`?

```
# a.py
from numpy import sin

def main(i):
    return sin(i)
```

and:

```
# b.py
from random import uniform

def main(j):
    return uniform(j)
```

You would not need to do the imports of `random.uniform` and `numpy.sin` in `master.py` because those functions. They're called by other functions in other modules; so the imports are needed in those other modules.

As well, [this Python Wiki page on performance](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead) indicates that the `imports`at the top of the file is superior for performance.